# How to check if a Internet enabled java program is the original one i made?

Tags: java, security, jar

I am writing a program which communicates with a server. But i want the server to only work with the original jar.

Is there anyway to do this? certificates etc?

Comment: @TAsk your answer is not related to the question

Answer (score 2):

[Sign your jar file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html)

And [verify the signature of the jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374170/how-to-verify-a-jar-signed-with-jarsigner-programmatically) on runtime.

Comment: This would be verifying the signature on the client side, not the server side. There's still no way of the server knowing if the client has been tampered with.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline it depends on a particular task. In some cases checking on the client side is enough. In some cases (for online games, to prevent cheating with patched clients) it is not.

Comment: Im using the client to send back data to the server but the data Needs to be legit. Havent Been able to try testing the cert yet because my java Broke....

Comment: Oh yea and the server is Another jar not an http server