# Java program to verify digital signature signed by signtool

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, digital-certificate, signtool

I have digitally signed a file(either .exe or .dll not a jar file) using SignTool.
Signtool can also verify the digital signature.
But my requirement is to check digital signature of file signed by signtool using java program.

I searched on internet but didn't find any info.
Could you please give me pointers regarding the same?

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify a jar signed with jarsigner programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374170/how-to-verify-a-jar-signed-with-jarsigner-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. My file here is an exe or dll file which was already signed using SignTool. Its not a jar file. I need to verify signature using java program

Answer (score -1):

**Signing Code**

> jarsigner -keystore c:/my.keystore -storepass ozziepassword e:/securityApplet.jar ozzie

**Verify Code:**

> jarsigner -verify e:/securityApplet.jar

---

To verify signature:

```
   Signature signer = null;
    try {
        signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Verify : No Such Algorith Exception." + e.getMessage();
    }
    try {
        result = signer.verify(digitalSignature);
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Verify : Signature Exception." + e.getMessage();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks TBM. My file here is an exe or dll file which was already signed using SignTool. Its not a jar file. I need to verify signature using java program

Comment: @jitendrabhati no idea about .exe and dll file. as I have used applet. I edit my post. it may help you.

Comment: Thanks TBM. What is digitalSignature in below code statement: result = signer.verify(digitalSignature);  Pls share that code snippet as well.

Comment: refer it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#verify(byte[])