# How to verify the digital signature of .EXE or DLL in Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, signtool

I would like to verify the digital signature of calling application ( .Exe file ) using Java API, i could see similar question posted for this but its unanswered

[Java program to verify digital signature signed by signtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915753/java-program-to-verify-digital-signature-signed-by-signtool)

In short I am looking for a Java option of below commands to verify signature of abc.exe

Powershell:

```
powershell get-process -Id pid | select -Expand modules|select -expand filename
```

pid is the process id of the abc.exe file here.

signtool:

```
signtool.exe verify /v abc.exe
```

Comment: How about executing it and then getting the output? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007425/get-output-from-a-process

Comment: Thanks @DanField for quick response, i already did this by spawning a process of  singtool.exe /  powershell then capturing the output, but our Security Architect has not approved it saying "spawning new process" is not a secure option and we should use JAVA API

Comment: Don't think you're going to find a Java API - signtool is part of the Windows SDK, there's likely a Windows API call for it that you might be able to use JNI to call if you can find the documentation for it...

Comment: Our SecureBlackbox (Java edition) includes Authenticode classes that let you sign and verify signatures of PE files (EXE and DLLs).

Comment: Thanks DanField for your comments. 
Thanks @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp  for sharing the details about your JDK. Could you please let us know if these security jars are available for download, so that i can download and import in my project

Comment: @Yogesh_JavaJ2EE yes, you can download SecureBlackbox on https://www.eldos.com/sbb/download-release.php