# Terminate Linux script if jarsigner verifies a jar that is unsigned

Tags: linux, bash, jarsigner

I would like to use jarsigner as part of a script and the script to terminate if the jar/zip is unsigned (or not signed by AWS in my particular case)

I was hoping I can configure jarsigner to return a non zero exit code when the jar is unsigned so that I can rely on it terminating my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/bash

set -e

jarsigner -verify -certs -strict my_jar_file.jar

# continue
```

Jarsigner will simply echo that the jar is unsigned but exit code is 0:

```
no manifest.

jar is unsigned.
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Note: I'm using bash...

Comment: Please show us output samples

Comment: How do you check the exit code?

Comment: I've tried `echo $?` for jarsigner which printed 0. The idea was to rely on `set -e` to "check" the exit code.

Comment: Try: `jarsigner -verify -certs -strict my_jar_file.jar | grep -q 'jar is unsigned'  && exit 1`

Comment: Parsing the output of the jarsinger seems wrong to me... What if newer versions change the message (unlikely but still...)

Comment: Reduce the characteristics of *re*, allow case insensitive: `... | grep -iq 'unsigned\|not signed'`

Comment: @EmanuelGeorgeHategan If *verification tool* can't return a result code and don't produce other files, output, the only way is to parsing tool's output.

Comment: I'm with you... I was hoping I don't need to resort to parsing the output as this seems wrong to me.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub fair enough. Am I using the wrong tool? What do people usually do? I was hoping this is a fairly common scenario and there is an idiomatic way of doing this...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know! I always avoid working with Java.

Comment: Maybe this: [How to verify a jar signed with jarsigner programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374170/1765658)

Comment: Note that in general, `set -e; foo` is better replaced with `foo || exit` (or, in a context where one wants to exit the function or file being sourced, passing through the exit status of the command that failed without exiting the shell, `foo || return`); see [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises)

Comment: Really, though, if `-verify -strict` doesn't return a nonzero exit status for content that isn't signed, report that as a bug, and expect that you _will_ need to do something ugly (like parsing stdout/stderr) to work around it. At least try to lean on the smarter flavors of ugly and fail on a nonzero exit status _in addition to_ failing when you recognize content you're looking for in stdout or stderr.

Comment: Either catch the output of `jarsigner` and use an `if` statement to see whether it contains the error message you are interested in, or if you **insist** in using `set -e`, just pipe it to `grep -q`. If the pattern is not found, `grep` will set exit code 1. Don't forget to check beforehand, whether jarsigner writes its message to stdout or to stderr.